# How to use REGEXP in INSERT INTO SELECT statement to copy number values only before insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have insert into select statement to copy value from one table to another.

There's am mobile column from both tables but in the source table the mobile number has a text attached to it like this : `Primary contact : 1234567890`.

So I'd like to copy only the 1234567890 part of the mobile.

I've done this using subquery with REGEXP:

```
INSERT INTO employee (employee_number, mobile) 

SELECT eb.employee_number,(SELECT mobile FROM employee_bulkadd_staging WHERE mobile REGEXP '^[0-9]+$')

FROM employee_bulkadd_staging eb
```

But it inserts NULL value to my mobile column.

I've also done this:

```
   INSERT INTO employee (employee_number, mobile) 

    SELECT eb.employee_number,eb.mobile REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'

    FROM employee_bulkadd_staging eb
```

But that inserts 0 as value.

Please let me know what is the best way to do this. Or what could I be doing wrong using REGEXP? Thanks.

Comment: _NOTE for next time_ - `Primary_contact` should have been a column and contain just the phone number

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Hello. Yes but it's coming from a different source and that's the default value. I have to pre-process this data before inserting to my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do [`INSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) and [`SUBSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( mobile FROM INSTR(mobile, ':')+1) 
FROM employee_bulkadd_staging
```

Comment: I am currently looking at substring and I think can just use it without INSTR which I don't know yet what is it for. Not so sure though.

Comment: You could if you know FOR SURE that the phone number ALWAYS starts in a specific column.

Comment: I used it like this as a subquery (SELECT SUBSTRING(mobile,17) AS ExtractString FROM employee_bulkadd_staging) then I can insert if it's only one row I'm copying from the source table. but gets an error "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" if there's more than one row to be inserted.

Comment: You  need a WHERE clause so you only get the data related to this employee

Comment: How silly of me. I'm still enclosing it in a parenthesis like a subquery . When I can just direct add SUBSTRING(mobile,17) in my first SELECT statement and it will insert more than 1 row without the ```subquery more than 1 row``` error.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)

```
INSERT INTO employee (employee_number, mobile) 

SELECT eb.employee_number,REPLACE(eb.mobile,'Primary contact : ','')

FROM employee_bulkadd_staging eb
```

Comment: I haven't. Let me try this.  Though I'm sure I will always have the 'Primary contact' string if it doesn't exist what result could I expect?

Comment: if there are only few strings which appear before phone number, I'd suggest that you replace them out using nested replace like  `REPLACE(REPLACE(original_string,'ABC',''),'XYZ','')`

Comment: if you have many random values then you need to take out digits from the column.

Comment: I was able to insert a row. But it inserted 'Primary Contact' instead of the mobile number. I used your example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,"[0-9]+") as col1 from test;
```

Test example:

```
create table test (
col1 varchar(255));

insert into test values
('Primary contact : 1234567890.'),
('1');
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> amount
> 1234567890
> 1
> ```

In your case :

```
INSERT INTO employee ( employee_number, 
                       mobile
                      ) 
SELECT eb.employee_number,
       ( SELECT mobile 
         FROM employee_bulkadd_staging 
         WHERE mobile  REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,"[0-9]+")
         )

FROM employee_bulkadd_staging eb
```

Comment: I have tried this but getting a syntax error. Does this work in MySQL?

Comment: @quielfala yes it works, but I think you must have MySQL 8+ version

Comment: Oh I have version 5. that's why.